# How to read the content of a .pdf file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have a scenario to automate the PDF contents. How to retrieve the content of the PDF file in nodejs.

I am completely blocked for this. Although there are few posts on `pdf2jsona` and `jsonreader` but those are not working for me. Any help will be appreciated for the same.

```
var pdfParser = new PDFParser();
fs.readFile(pdfFilePath, function(err, pdfBuffer) {
    pdfParser.parseBuffer(pdfBuffer);
}, function(pdfBuffer){
    pdfParser.parseBuffer(pdfBuffer);
})
```

> Error: Invalid parameter array, need either .data or .url
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)

Comment: Hi. Is there a particular issue you identified with these 2 libraries?

Comment: Hi Sebas, I added the code snippet and error to the question itself. Please have a look and let me know anything I am missing as I am new to nodejs

Comment: I am not certain the error comes from the pdfParser but rather the fs object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it's working perfectly. Install fs and pdf2json by running the below commands.
`npm install pdf2json` and `npm install fs`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PDFParser = require('pdf2json');
var path = osHomedir();
var homepath = path.replace(new RegExp('\\' + path.sep, 'g'), '/');
var pdfFilePath = homepath + '/Downloads/' + 'filename.pdf';

if (fs.existsSync(pdfFilePath)) {
  //Read the content of the pdf from the downloaded path
  var pdfParser = new PDFParser(browser, 1);
  pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", function (errData) {
     console.error(errData.parserError)
  });
  pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", function (pdfData) {
  //console.log('here is the content: '+pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
  browser.assert.ok(pdfParser.getRawTextContent().indexOf(textToVerify) > -1);
  });

  pdfParser.loadPDF(pdfFilePath);
} else {
    console.log('OOPs file not present in the downloaded folder');
    //Throw an error if the file is not found in the path mentioned
    browser.assert.ok(fs.existsSync(pdfFilePath));
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is browser here . I am also using same but i am getting this error :  ReferenceError: browser is not defined
Thanks

Comment: You need to explain what the `browser` variable is.

Comment: The documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json is a pretty good starting point for using pdf2json

Answer (score 2):

```
 const fs = require("fs");
 const PdfReader = require('pdfreader').PdfReader;
  fs.readFile("E://file streaming in node js//demo//read.pdf", (err, pdfBuffer) => {
    // pdfBuffer contains the file content
    new PdfReader().parseBuffer(pdfBuffer, function(err, item){
       if (err)
           callback(err);
        else if (!item)
            callback();
         else if (item.text)
            console.log(item.text);
          });
       });
```