# Is there a way to get a data from a pdf file and interact it for a web page search?

Tags: node.js, pdf, web-scraping

Working on a web scraping project, which I decided to use node js to scrape the data from the website.

Long story short, it is a website that in their search engine, you place the UID (unique ID) of the company and you find there the information about the company that you are searching for. To have that UID of the company, I need to got to another web page that has the companies listed, download the pdf file, and inside the pdf file is the UID. I take the UID from the pdf file and make the search as I told you above.

My question is that is there a possible way to do this kind of interaction between web pages and pdf file content?

I chose to do it with Node js, but if there is another way in another programming language I would consider it as well.

Comment: Might wanna take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41635540/14998487